# How to know if an iPhone/iPod/iPad has a passcode security (or the data protection is enabled)? (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, ios4, data-protection

Is there a way to know if the user of an iDevice has the passcode set in the device? or maybe..
How to know if Data Protection is enabled?

My intention is to know if the data protection is enabled, and related to the data gathered
around the web, it is directly related to the device passcode.

I ended in this question, [How can I find out if the iPhone user currently has a passcode set and encryption enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806455/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-iphone-user-currently-has-a-passcode-set-and-encryption), but is a little old, maybe someone founds an alternative.

Comment: That other thread is basically still correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out if the iPhone user currently has a passcode set and encryption enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806455/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-iphone-user-currently-has-a-passcode-set-and-encryptio)