# iOS5: How can I find out if the iPhone user currently has a passcode set and encryption enabled?

Tags: ios5

Seems to me, that the iOS 4 hint ([How can I find out if the iPhone user currently has a passcode set and encryption enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806455/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-iphone-user-currently-has-a-passcode-set-and-encryptio))  does not work any more. I want make sure that user has chosen a passcode before he can use my app, but I did not find any way in iOS5 to find that out. Creating a file and comparing like this

```
 BOOL fileProtectionEnabled = [NSFileProtectionNone isEqualToString:[testFileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileProtectionKey]];
```

does not make a difference in an locked and a unlocked device.

I also tried to create a file like this

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentFile contents:[@"super secret file contents" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication forKey:NSFileProtectionKey]];
```

expecting that the documentFile would only be created when there is a passcode, but it's also created without a passcode.