# how to check if a passcode or screenlock is set using the Key Chain APIs in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ios

is there any way to check whether the screen lock or the pass code is enabled using any public API.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible by checking the NSFileProtectionKey property of a given file.
Please have a look at the following resolution:

[Check NSFileProtectionKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806455/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-iphone-user-currently-has-a-passcode-set-and-encryptio)

Comment: Hi,I have checked the link but every time its returning the same value NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionNone;